# Textarea autosize based on existing content can't work in chrome but can work in firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, autosize

I'm trying to make textarea autogrow based on existing content.When the content of textarea is too long,the textarea isn't autogrow to show the whole content in chrome.I should input '\n' ,and the textarea will show the whole content. But in firefox, textarea can show the whole content.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<textarea id="currentValue" class="auto-size" cols="110" onpropertychange="if(this.scrollHeight&gt;80) this.style.posHeight=this.scrollHeight+5"></textarea>
```

when the content is too long,onpropertychange can't work in chrome,but it can work in firefox.

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autosize.input.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function(){

    $.getJSON('data_get', function(ans){
        //initial textarea and ensure textarea autogrow only in vertical
        $('#currentValue').val(ans.currentValue);
        $('#currentValue').css({
            'resize':'vertical'
        }   
        );
            .
            .
            .
        $('.auto-size').autosize({append: "\n"});
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I look up many files to find the answer,but finally I find the answer in Jquery documentation.[enter link description here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)

I modify the script code like this:

```
$('.auto-size').autosize({append: "\n"}).trigger('autosize.resize');
```

And when the content is too long, textarea can show the whole content in chrome(onpropertychange worked!!!).